# How to implement logging of all changes mysql database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

I need to track all changes in database: update, insert, delete. I want know WHO and WHAT change.

Need `log` table with columns:

1. Date.
2. Table name.
3. Column.
4. Old value.
5. New value.
6. IP.

What is the best way to implement this?

Are there ready-made solutions?

I tried use triggers on update / insert / delete. This is a good solution? Or maybe I do not know something about the correct logging in mysql?

My trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `user_update_trigger`
AFTER UPDATE ON `users`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

DECLARE done int default false;
DECLARE col_name CHAR(255);

DECLARE counter INTEGER(11);

DECLARE column_cursor cursor for SELECT `column_name`
                    FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
                    WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='test' 
                    AND `TABLE_NAME`='users';

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

open column_cursor;

myloop: loop

fetch column_cursor into col_name;

if done then
    leave myloop;
end if;

/*SET @old_val = OLD.{{col_name}}; <------ HOW GET VALUE? */
/*SET @new_val = NEW.{{col_name}};<------ HOW GET VALUE? */

if @old_val <> @new_val then
    /*INSERT INTO `log` ....*/
end if;


end loop;

close column_cursor;

END;
```

Comment: Are you trying to create a version history table? If so that can get really messy if the schema of the original ever changes. I've found dumping the original row in some neutral format (e.g. JSON) into a history table via the application layer is often the best way to tackle this. That way you never have to apply migrations to the history table, and you can subjectively interpret old records if you ever need to roll back.

Comment: Rollback is not needed... I need just understand who (IP) when and what edited in database. The idea of dumping data in JSON is nice... Do I need a trigger for this?

Comment: MySQL 5.7 supports native JSON columns, so it's even nicer than it used to be.

Comment: I need to make a trigger on update . I will save old and new row in json format to log table. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: A trigger can do it, but MySQL's procedural language is extremely clunky compared to other RDBMS platforms. Postgres, as an example, has much better JSON support, plus JavaScript V8 is a natively supported procedural scripting language. Just a consideration if you're in the early stages of building out something for which this is a core concern.

Comment: This application is already about 10 years old. So I don't have to choose ... Thank's for your help. I'll try JSON + triggers.

Comment: If you do come up with a solution, it's worth adding a self-answer as that's something other people would likely be interested in.

Answer (score 0):

enable [mysql audit log filtering](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/audit-log-filtering.html#audit-log-filtering-enabling-logging).
You can do something like

```
    {
  "filter": {
    "class": [
      {
        "name": "connection",
        "event": [
          { "name": "connect" },
          { "name": "disconnect" }
        ]
      },
      { "name": "general" },
      {
        "name": "table_access",
        "event": [
          { "name": "insert" },
          { "name": "delete" },
          { "name": "update" }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

or

```
    "event": [
  { "name": "select", "log": false },
  { "name": "insert", "log": true },
  { "name": "delete", "log": true },
  { "name": "update", "log": true }
]
```